# Can we say that the point $(-3,2)$ is the local minimum?

Tags: calculus, continuity, maxima-minima

[image]

For this graph can we say that the point $(-3,2)$ is the local minimum?

My attempt.

For any $x\in(-3-\delta,-3+\delta)$ there is no small $\epsilon>0$ , such that $\forall \delta\in(0,\epsilon)$ if $0<\delta<\epsilon$ then $f(x)>f(-3)$. So, this point is not a local minimum.

Is this attempt correct?

Comment: A problem with your attempt is that you write $x\in(-3-\delta,-3+\delta)$ without having said what $\delta$ is.

Comment: @Taladris did you read the completely?

Comment: I don't need. If $\delta$ is not introduced before using it, the sentence is quite meaningless.

Comment: What does "think of the delta as fish" mean o_O? Also, the antecedent of "if $0<\delta<\epsilon$, then $f(x)>f(-3)$" is independent from the consequent. That should be a big hint that there is a problem with what you wrote...

Comment: "For every $\delta>0$"? "For some $\delta>0$"? "For every $0<\delta<\pi$"? "For every $\delta$ such that $(-3-\delta,-3+\delta)$ is included in the domain of $f$"? There is a plethora of options and many of them would change drastically the meaning of the whole sentence.

Comment: Writing $\delta>0$ is your least important problem. Consider my other comments.

Comment: @Taladris yes you are right

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that you may misunderstand the definition of local minimum. I think the definition is $f(x_0)$ is a local minimum if there exists $\delta>0$ so that $\forall x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, $f(x)\geq f(x_0)$. Therefore $(-3,2)$ is not a local minimum.

Answer (score 1):

For a local minimum at a point $x=x_0$, the points in any neighborhood around this point, the function values must be larger than at the point $x_0$.

This is not the case at $x=-3$, where the function value is $2$. The points in any neighborhood around this point have lower function value.

Comment: Actually, what I want to say is that this point does not have such a small neighborhood.  Because the function breaks from the left and falls to $ -1.$

Comment: Only the ''empty neighborhood'' works. But $\epsilon>0$ and so the neighborhood is per se not empty.

Comment: @Westenfux There is no empty neighborhood. By definition, a neighborhood contains an open set that contains the point it's a neighborhood of.